# How do I contain a circular gravity Field

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am experimenting with SpriteKit and swift and have an idea for a cool game but I need a few suggests from someone more advanced them myself. Here is what I would like to do:
I would like to have a normal landscape view With a circle inside of the view that is a contained gravity field of it's own. Objects will be flying around the outside but the the game play happens on the inside of the circle. WHAT WOULD BE THE BEST WAY to approach this?
I am having a hard time with the idea of a contained field and how to keep it separated.  Any suggestions to get me pointed in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
    let field = SKFieldNode.turbulenceFieldWithSmoothness(0.5, animationSpeed: 0.1)
    //let field = SKFieldNode.radialGravityField(???)
    self.addChild(field)
    field.region = SKRegion(size: CGSize(width: 300, height: 100))
    field.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width * 0.5, self.size.height * 0.5)


    wallsNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    wallsNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 240)
    wallsNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    self.addChild(wallsNode)
```

Comment: Why the [ios6.1] tag? SpriteKit requires iOS 7, and physics fields require iOS 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any kind of `SKFieldNode`, including radial gravity fields, has an associated [`SKRegion`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKRegion_Ref/index.html) that determines its area of effect. Create a circular region (e.g. `SKRegion(radius:30)`) and apply it to your gravity field, and it'll only affect things within that circle.

Comment: I experimented with that but don't understand how I will contain it. With a empty shape node or a path with a physics body?

Comment: What do you mean "contain it", then? The region limits where bodies can be affected by the field. And the field is its own node—it doesn't need to be a child of a sprite or shape node (though it can be if you want to give it a visible representation).

Comment: Yes! I Got it Now. I put an edge loop to make it happen! Thanks for the push in the right diretion! YOU ARE DA MAN!